# make error while install the gr-plasma in the last step

Tags: github, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

```
make[2]: *** [apps/CMakeFiles/plasma_calibrate_delay.dir/build.make:131：apps/plasma_calibrate_delay] 错误 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:408：apps/CMakeFiles/plasma_calibrate_delay.dir/all] 错误 2
make: *** [Makefile:146：all] 错误 2
```

i met a problem while install the gr-plasma in the "make",does anyone know how to fix the problem ?i would really appreciate that!

i tried look it up in the git hub "issues",there are also same questions with me.But i still do not know how to fix it

Comment: you need to read further up. The actual error message isn't shown in your question.

Comment: i commented  out of lines in the /apps/cmakelist.txt,and i can install it successfully,i do not know if it will affected my design